# Find Minimal Spanning Tree Using Prim's Algorith

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms, trees

What will be the minimal spanning tree using Prim's Algorithm for this graph

[image]

Also ***can i draw a tree and assign the weights as i like,will there be a minimal spanning tree for such a graph***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your second question first, any graph has a [minimum weight spanning tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_spanning_tree), though it may not be unique. So you can assign the weights however you like and a minimal weight spanning tree can be found.

---

To run [Prim's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prim%27s_algorithm), you need to pick a starting vertex and consider all the edges connected to it. Pick the smallest that connects to a new vertex and then repeat.

For example with your graph, let's start with vertex $a$. The edges connecting $a$ to the rest of the graph are of weights $2,4,5$ so we add the weight $2$ edge to our tree and vertex $b$ to our set of visited vertices, which includes our starting vertex. Now we look at all edges leaving our set of visited vertices $\{a,b\}$ and we have $4$ edges to consider with weights $3,4,5,10$. Since $3$ is the smallest and goes to vertex we have not visited before, we add the edge of weight $3$ to our tree and $f$ to our list of visited vertices. Repeat this until finished. Only add an edge that connects the visited vertices to an unvisited vertex.

Comment: So in an exam,i can draw any connected weight graph and assign weights as like to find the minimal spanning tree by applying prim's right?

Comment: I can't answer what your exam requirements are but any weighted graph has a minimal spanning tree. If you want to guarantee said tree to be unique, then you need the weights on the edges to be unique.

Comment: The weights on the edges need not be unique,as the textbook itself uses same weight for more than 1 edges.That tree is so large that i cannot learn it by-heart. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Weight edges being unique isn't necessary for finding a minimal spanning tree. It isn't necessary for finding a unique minimal spanning tree as the graph you have here has a unique minimal spanning tree. But if all the edges are unique, then the minimal spanning tree is guaranteed to be unique.

Comment: Okay,i understand